# Java/Android studio : For loop - Same data shows multiple times

Tags: java, android, android-studio, for-loop, realm

So I am trying to create this page that compares a user's interest with other users and shows the list of all those users.. Now, with the for loop i created, one particular user's name repeats until the end of the loop. I only one one name per username to appear on the textfield.. However, I don't know how to do that.. Here's my code for showing users with common interests:

```
 Realm realm= Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        RealmResults<interests> result=realm.where(interests.class).findAll();
        RealmResults<Users> user=realm.where(Users.class).findAll();
     for(int i=0;i<result.size();i++)
            {
                for(int j=0;j<result.size();j++)
                {
                    if(result.get(i).getId().equals(userid))
                    {
                        if(result.get(i).getInterest().equals(result.get(j).getInterest()))
                        {
                            if(!result.get(j).getId().equals(userid)) {
                                users = result.get(j).getId();
                                interestss.append("Interests :" + result.get(i).getInterest());
                            }

                        }
                        id.append("\n"+users);

                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 for(int i=0;i<result.size();i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<result.size();j++)
            {
                if(result.get(i).getId().equals(userid))
                {
                    if(result.get(i).getInterest().equals(result.get(j).getInterest()))
```

I'm almost 98% sure that you shouldn't even need to write this kind of code if you use Realm's query system and a link query, instead of looping and comparing things manually.

```
RealmResults<Interests> interests = realm.where(Interests.class)
                                         .equalTo("user.userId", userId)
                                         .findAll();
```

Which should be possible if you have a backlink from Interests to Users.

```
// in Interests class
@LinkingObjects("interest")
private final RealmResults<User> user = null;
```